Logical error rate for Hypergraph Product code
I've recently written up circuit-level noise syndrome extraction simulation for Hypergraph Product code as a practice. However, I am unable to reproduce the numerical results obtained in relevant literature. My workflow for the simulation is :
Syndrome extraction circuit with single-qubit ancilla
An overall BPOSD decoding at the end with order osd-cs10
I'm getting unusually high logical error rate, e.g. [400,16,6] HGP code, p=0.001, rounds=6, Logical error rate per round is about 0.2, which is clearly not correct. I'm wondering if anyone else doing similar things have the same observation? That when you naively simulate HGP with BPOSD it's not very good? Or what else could go wrong?
My debugging attempts:
I've checked the code for syndrome extraction, as a sanity check I tried HGP with repetition code (so unrotated surface code) + matching decoder. It has comparable performance with the inbuilt surface code circuit, and I also checked all indivisual components, the circuit matches my implementation. Besides the code runs smoothly so I think the circuit itself is less likely to be wrong.
Therefore I think the problem is in decoding. Maybe should I try sliding windows or the BP + BPOSD as in Xu et al? But for BP + BPOSD I'm not sure how to integrate this into the decoder. According to the authors, they perform BP decoding after every syndrome extraction and BPOSD at the end. However, I don't think with Stim can handle mid-circuit decoding. How should I do this?
